# Is it possible to use gdb in terminal for iOS?

Tags: ios5, ios4, xcode4.2

I am basically from linux background, Once i application is launched in iPhone device, or iPhone simulator, any possibility to use gdb in terminal?

Comment: I'm not certain about your question, but you *can* type in commands at the debugger ("`(lldb)`") prompt within Xcode while your app is running on your iDevice.